# Request retag/merge of [truncate], [truncated], and [truncation]

Tags: discussion, support, retag-request

While retagging a question today about the `TRUNC()` function, I noticed a couple of possible tags for truncation:

[truncate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/truncate) (1040 questions)

[truncation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/truncation) (228 questions)

[truncated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/truncated) (150 questions)

I have read through some of them, and the last two seem to just be the same tag but using different tenses of the English language. There seems to be three types of questions here:

- Use of the SQL statement `TRUNCATE TABLE`
- Truncating entire files or text logs
- Use of various program `TRUNC()` methods or equivalent functions

There is no real way to separate those types of questions into three different tags because they all use the same `TRUNCATE` proword to invoke. Also, even though the functions work in different ways on different aspects of data, it is all still the same basic principle.

Therefore, I recommend we retag/merge [truncation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/truncation) and [truncated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/truncated) and end up with the single tag [truncate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/truncate). If a single merge is not warranted, would it be better to merge them all into two potentially new tags: [truncate-sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/truncate-sql) and [truncate-functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/truncate-functions)?

Comment: We can probably use some combination of [tag:truncate-table], [tag:sql-truncate], [tag:trunc] (but more specific, probably) and/or whatever else makes sense (having a tag for every truncate function out there would not be the worst thing in the world). I don't think we need a tag for generic truncation - that's too broad.

Comment: @Dukeling Maybe two tags then: [tag:sql-truncate] and [tag:truncation-functions]?

Comment: These tags are also used for decimal number truncation vs. string truncation. These two are distinct, but I don’t think there needs to be a tag for this generic truncation.